# ordering ASC or DESC based on numbers but for non numeric rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a db table which has columns with non numeric data, such as  ( 1 - 100 ) and ( / ).

So when ordering based on this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `kw_keywords` ORDER BY `kw_keywords`.`position` ASC
```

it returns rows with / at the begining while it must be 1 at the begining

How can I put all rows with / or Null to the end of number based ordering ?

Comment: Is it really related to my question or you just giving me negative and closing the topic?

Comment: I guess you have to decide; but I wouldn't have commented if I didn't think it was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional sorting:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `kw_keywords` 
ORDER BY `position` IS NULL, `position` = 0, `position` + 0
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `kw_keywords` 
ORDER BY COALESCE(`position`, 0) = 0, `position` + 0
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnttVZ2uA3RyCEfHRPGLHT/0).

Comment: Exactly, I was doing the same, my local server crashes when I run this query, I think it is related to my environment not to the query.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to convert it to Laravel syntax without using the raw query solution ?

Comment: A crash for this simple code is very strange. For Laravel I can't help you.

Comment: ok I found this working for laravel framework : ->orderByRaw(' '.$order.' IS NULL, '.$order.'  = 0, '.$order.'  + 0 '.$dir.' ')

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY if(`kw_keywords`.`position`= '' or `kw_keywords`.`position`is null,1,0),`kw_keywords`.`position` ASC